# Why do separate connections to MySQL made with mysql_real_connect seem to have limits set on inserts?

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading

I'm trying to figure out why my connections to a MySQL database seem to have a very small limit (less than 100) on the number of INSERTs each connection can make per second.  I've read about connection limits, but these all talk about per hour limits.  What I'm experiencing is a per second limit.

I'm using the MySQL C API to open connections (one per thread).  In the thread I just loop as fast as I can making calls to mysql_query.  I run for 10 seconds, counting the number of queries and report these once finished.

Using **SELECT** statements for my queries I get the following results:

- 2 Threads : 9800 accesses per sec per thread (9800*2 = 18K total accesses per sec)
- 5 Threads : 8400 accesses per sec per thread (8400*5 = 42K total accesses)
- 10 threads: 7300 accesses per sec per thread (7300*10 = 73K total accesses)

Using **INSERT** statements for my queries I get the following results

- 2 Threads : **169** accesses per sec per thread (338 total accesses)
- 5 Threads : **168** accesses per sec per thread (840 total accesses)
- 10 threads: **167** accesses per sec per thread (1670 total accesses)
- 20 threads: **165** accesses per sec per thread (3300 total accesses)
- 40 threads: **161** accesses per sec per thread (6400 total accesses)

It appears there is some sort of limit set.  A connection can't INSERT more than 169 per second, even though when I have 40 threads running, the MySQL database can handle of 6000 INSERTS.

How do I increase the number of INSERTS a connection can make?

I have a simple test schema I'm using:

> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.tbl (
>     tbl_idx INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>     tbl_unique_id INT NOT NULL,
>     type INT NOT NULL,
>     date_time DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>     name LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>     description LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
>     notes LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL
>   );`

My C code to run these tests:

My main function:

```
int running = 1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int secs = 10;
  int threadcnt = 20;
  int i;
  pthread_t readers[50], writers[50];

  mysql_library_init(0, NULL, NULL);

  for (i=0; i<threadcnt; i++)
  {
    pthread_create( &readers[i], NULL, dbtest_read, NULL);
    pthread_create( &writers[i], NULL, dbtest_write, NULL);
  }

  sleep(secs);
  running = 0;

  for (i=0; i<threadcnt; i++)
  {
    pthread_join(readers[i], NULL);
    pthread_join(writers[i], NULL);
  }

  mysql_library_end();

  return 0;
```

}

My SELECT reader thread:

```
static void *dbtest_read(void *arg)
{
  char query_insert[1024] = "INSERT INTO tbl ( tbl_unique_id,  type,  date_time,  name,  notes) VALUES ('100', '33', NOW(), 'TestTarget', 'Alot of good notes here')";
  MYSQL mysql;
  MYSQL *conn;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  MYSQL_RES *result;
  long cnt = 0;
  struct timespec start, stop;
  double elapsed = 0.0;

  printf("Starting Read Thread\n");
  mysql_init(&mysql);

  conn = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost", "sms", "ar.ch111", "test", 0, 0, 0);

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start);

  while (running)
  {
    mysql_query(conn, query_select);
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    cnt++;
    usleep(0);
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&stop);

  elapsed = (double) (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (double) (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1.0e9;

  printf("***DB Read Test*** selects: %ld  rate: %.2f /sec\n",cnt, ((float)(cnt)/elapsed));

  mysql_close(conn);

  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

My INSERT writer thread:

```
static void *dbtest_write(void *arg)
{
char query_select[1024] = "SELECT tbl_unique_id, type, date_time, name FROM tbl WHERE tbl_idx = 1";
  MYSQL mysql;
  MYSQL *conn;
  long cnt = 0;
  struct timespec start, stop;
  double elapsed = 0.0;

  printf("Starting Write Thread\n");
  mysql_init(&mysql);

  conn = mysql_real_connect(&mysql,"localhost", "sms", "ar.ch111", "test", 0, 0, 0);

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start);

  while (running)
  {
    mysql_query(conn, query_insert);
    cnt++;
    usleep(0);
  }
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&stop);

  elapsed = (double) (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + (double) (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1.0e9;

  printf("***DB Write Test*** inserts: %ld  rate: %.2f /sec\n",cnt, ((float)(cnt)/elapsed));

  mysql_close(conn);

  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just a guess here, but is it possible that what you are seeing is MySQL grouping the flushes to disk [(group commit)](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/12/30/an-easy-way-to-describe-mysqls-binary-log-group-commit.html)? Try using engine=blackhole to check if your disk is the limiting factor.

Comment: I take it your test machine has fewer than 40 cores?

Comment: Yes, using engine=blackhole changes the behavior.  With the blackhole engine I now see the same access rates for both reads and writes.  I've tried this code on two different linux boxes, both have very fast generation 3 solid state drives.  I can write 100s of MB out to disk per second, so it surprises me that the disk would be a limiting factor.  Is there something else that is limiting it?

Comment: Why would the disk be the limiting factor while adding more threads improves overall performance?

Comment: OK, from following lmz's suggestion with blackhole engine got me thinking.  I changed the engine of my table to innodb and enabled this variable 'innodb_api_enable_binlog=1' in my.cnf.  Bingo, now I'm seeing 4800 writes per thread!  I'm going to try tuning some of the other parameters, but I'm well on my way to getting the performance up to where I would expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms indicates that it has to do with I/O latency and bandwidth. Since using a single thread blocks while the server executes the query, an approximate equation for the time taken for the execution of a single query would be:

```
T = L + S / B
```

Where

```
T represents time to execute a single query
L represents the I/O latency
S represents the size of the data
B represents the I/O bandwidth
```

As such, the maximum number of transaction per seconds would be:

```
TPS = 1 / (L + S / B)
```

Using several threads, the time taken to execute several queries in parallel becomes:

```
T = L + N * S / B
```

where N represents the number of threads.

Notice that the latency incurred by several threads working in parallel is not duplicated. The I/O bandwidth affects the aggregated data transfers though. The number of transactions per second becomes:

```
TPS = N / (L + N * S / B)
```

As the number of threads grows, latency effect will eventually become negligible and you end up with `TPS ~= S / B` meaning that you go as fast as your I/O bandwidth allows to. With the blackhole engine, latency becomes negligible which explains the behavior you have seen.

Other parameters such as disk caching affect performance. Overall, I think that this explains pretty well what is going on. MySQL does not allow executing several queries over the same database connection, otherwise that would be a good experiment to make to confirm my theory. Note that you did not push the number of threads far enough to hit the I/O bandwidth bottleneck.

Comment: After more testing, I confirmed that I was truly IO bound.  Not in a sense of raw bandwidth to the disk, but the time it takes to write+flush to the disk.  Flushing is very expensive in time.  As I added more threads, those transactions were being grouped together with MySQL grouping, but before a connection could make another write, their previous write needed to be flushed to disk.

Comment: By changing two paramaters: 'innodb_api_enable_binlog=1' and 'innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0' and moving to the innodb engine, I told MySQL to batch a large group of transactions and flush them to disk at the same time.  This has risks with data loss, but for my application, I can handle those risks.  Thus my per thread write performance now is very similar to the per thread read performance.

Comment: Of course, disk caching plays a big role in this case. What you are saying does not invalidate what I said. You got rid of the latency by avoiding the actual disk I/O to happen at each query. All of the actual I/Os are bundled at commit time. If that works for you then that's great. That said, your problem kept me thinking and I wanted to understand the cause of such behavior, and I believe I did. Also note that multiple threads achieve both performance and eliminate the risk of data loss. Not flushing the log at commit time might cause database inconsistency as you are aware of.